# change specific elements of strings

Tags: python, string

i have one store and 4 customers. lng , lat of store is 50,30 and lists of stores are:

```
lng_customers= [51,52,53,54]
lat_customers= [35,36,37,38]
```

I want to make these strings for all of them using a loop.

```
'your points are/{50},{30};{51},{35}'  
'your points are/{50},{30};{52},{36}' 
'your points are/{50},{30};{53},{37}' 
'your points are/{50},{30};{54},{38}'
```

how can I make these strings? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
lng_customers= [51,52,53,54]
lat_customers= [35,36,37,38]

for i, j in zip(lng_customers, lat_customers):
    print('your points are/{50},{30}; {%s}, {%s}' % (i, j))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need curly braces in your string, this will do the job:

```
lng_customers = [51, 52, 53, 54]
lat_customers = [35, 36, 37, 38]

string = 'your points are/{{50}},{{30}};{{{}}},{{{}}}'

for lng, lat in zip(lng_customers, lat_customers):
    print(string.format(lng, lat))
```

If not, do this:

```
string = 'your points are/50,30;{},{}'

for lng, lat in zip(lng_customers, lat_customers):
    print(string.format(lng, lat))
```

Alternatively:

```
string = 'your points are/{},{};{},{}'

for lng, lat in zip(lng_customers, lat_customers):
    print(string.format(50, 30, lng, lat))
```

Comment: Very nice approach to solve

Answer (score 0):

```
lng_customers = [51, 52, 53, 54]
lat_customers = [35, 36, 37, 38]
lng, lat = 50, 30

for i in range(len(lng_customers)):
    requiredString = "your points are/{" + f"{lng}" + "},{" + f"{lat}" + "};{" + f"{lng_customers[i]}" + "},{" +f"{lat_customers[i]}" + "}"
    print(requiredString)
```

#You can print it or store it somewhere as per your requirement